# In System.Linq.Dynamic.Select(), how to deal with a null object reference in a simple way?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am using dynamic LINQ (System.Linq.Dynamic)(you may find description here, http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/GettingStarted).

The following statement works well

```
Products.Select("new(ProductName, CategoryID.CategoryName as CategoryName)");
```

But I accidentally found when CategoryID is null, the results are empty. But I supposed it would return a record such as:

ProductName="Wine", CategoryName="" (or null).

Then I found a way to do so by

```
Products.Select("new(ProductName, iif(CategoryID==null,\"\",CategoryID.CategoryName) as CategoryName)");
```

The statement is ugly.

Do you have a better solution?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: "new(ProductName, CategoryID==null?null:CategoryID.CategoryName) as CategoryName)" worked. It seems a little simpler and more general to use null, as Cory mentioned.

Comment: A more ugly sample is : grand==null?null:(grand.parent==null?null:grand.parent.son).

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444851/null-reference-exception-in-a-dynamic-linq-expression). It isn't clear why the solution was accepted, but what I did see there is that you can do this:

```
"new(ProductName, iif(CategoryID==null,null,CategoryID.CategoryName) as CategoryName)"
```

instead of this:

```
"new(ProductName, iif(CategoryID==null,\"\",CategoryID.CategoryName) as CategoryName)"
```

It isn't any shorter, but to me it makes the code a bit more readable because you just use `null` instead of escaping the quotes.

Comment: "new(ProductName, CategoryID==null?null:CategoryID.CategoryName) as CategoryName)"